# Kafka Topic Message Versioning

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I publish messages to a kafka topic (outputTopic) in a format which my subscribers can understand.  I now wish to modify the format of these messages in a way which will break the existing topic consumers.

For example, I post objects, serialised in json format, but need to change the objects, and therefore the schema.

What is the best way to manage this type of change?  Should I alter the producer so that it publishes to a new topic (outputTopic2)?  Are there any better ways to manage this?

Comment: Different schema would usually require a separate topic, but Kafka will still accept the messages either way. If you don't want to edit any consumer code, it will need to be that way, though

Comment: historical events of old versions present in Kafka are important for future needs?

Comment: In theory, if you can ensure that consumers that support the new model consume from predictable partitions, then you could route messages with the new model to those partitions. You'd need to be careful that you don't mess up load balancing with this though. Maybe routing to consumer groups could help.

Answer (score 3):

Avro schemas will not solve the problem. You could update the consumers to handle both old and new versions whether or not there are schemas.

Instead, keep your producer as it is. Deploy an updated version that reads from the same data source and publishes data to a new topic with the new updated format.

Allow consumers to migrate from the old version to the new version before finally killing the old one.

Answer (score 2):

One clean way to do according to me, is to use [Schema registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/index.html) / [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org). Depending on how you use it, it will help you to guarantee backward / forward compatibility.